# How can I build on tag push only but not on branches with Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use Azure Pipelines to build a docker container. Everything works great except for the fact that the pipeline runs on every branch push (and builds all the way) when in fact I would like it to build only on tags that start with "v".

I am using bitbucket for git repo.

I've looked online and as far as I can tell from examples, my yml should be working

My trigger looks like this:

```
    trigger:
      tags:
        include:
        - 'v*'
      branches:
        exclude:
        - '*'
```

Unfortunately with this configuration, my pipeline builds on every branch instead of tags only.

I would like to be able to automatically build on pushing tags only, no branches, no PRs (right now it builds on branches and PRs but not on tags, at all).

Thanks!

EDIT: looks like merge (pull) requests ALWAYS get built and triggers can't prevent that by excluding branches. As long as webhook exists for merge requests, they will get built.

Comment: try to remove the `branches` section and keep only the tags.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk did that also, but nothing different. Also considered that in order to build a tag I may need to also allow the branch on which tags are made (aka master) but still no change.

Comment: @Andrei Dascalu Does my answer help you solve your problem? If yes,you can  [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).If not ,please kindly let me know.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue ,the reason is:

> Triggering on tags is not currently supported for Bitbucket Cloud
>   repos.

Please refer to the **Note** part of this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#tags). If you want tag trigger to work in yaml,you need to use another repo.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this already?

```
trigger:
- refs/tags/*
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but no change :(